On Heroku, I can't run the Laravel application
I can’t access the pages on Heroku, it gives a generic error 500. Does anyone have a solution for this?
I need to build the page using npm run dev at my location to render.
I tried changing the environment variable files and the Heroku Procfile.

[Screenshot of application in browser][1]
[Screenshot of Heroku logs][2]

Log:
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620194+00:00 app[web.1]: [previous exception] [object] (Exception(code: 0): Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: public/script.js. at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php:761)
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620202+00:00 app[web.1]: [stacktrace]
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620249+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php(279): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Vite->chunk()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620304+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/storage/framework/views/44fb48915db0428a65481620c7285aa0.php(26): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Vite->__invoke()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620337+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(124): require('...')
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620400+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(125): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620453+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620510+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(72): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620559+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(207): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620603+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(190): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620649+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(159): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620694+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/storage/framework/views/68037fbf354601ad5c27ca5ba5ac80ce.php(109): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620743+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(124): require('...')
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620798+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(125): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620852+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620910+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(72): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.620959+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(207): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621004+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(190): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621050+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(159): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621094+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621151+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621199+00:00 app[web.1]: #19 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(911): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621248+00:00 app[web.1]: #20 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(878): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621298+00:00 app[web.1]: #21 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621356+00:00 app[web.1]: #22 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621409+00:00 app[web.1]: #23 /app/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(29): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621464+00:00 app[web.1]: #24 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621531+00:00 app[web.1]: #25 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621589+00:00 app[web.1]: #26 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621657+00:00 app[web.1]: #27 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621717+00:00 app[web.1]: #28 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621784+00:00 app[web.1]: #29 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621841+00:00 app[web.1]: #30 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621906+00:00 app[web.1]: #31 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.621972+00:00 app[web.1]: #32 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622027+00:00 app[web.1]: #33 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622096+00:00 app[web.1]: #34 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622156+00:00 app[web.1]: #35 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622222+00:00 app[web.1]: #36 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622275+00:00 app[web.1]: #37 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622334+00:00 app[web.1]: #38 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622381+00:00 app[web.1]: #39 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622433+00:00 app[web.1]: #40 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(777): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622481+00:00 app[web.1]: #41 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(741): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622531+00:00 app[web.1]: #42 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(730): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622582+00:00 app[web.1]: #43 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622646+00:00 app[web.1]: #44 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622715+00:00 app[web.1]: #45 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622789+00:00 app[web.1]: #46 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622852+00:00 app[web.1]: #47 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622921+00:00 app[web.1]: #48 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.622989+00:00 app[web.1]: #49 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623047+00:00 app[web.1]: #50 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623115+00:00 app[web.1]: #51 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623175+00:00 app[web.1]: #52 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623250+00:00 app[web.1]: #53 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623316+00:00 app[web.1]: #54 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623379+00:00 app[web.1]: #55 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623432+00:00 app[web.1]: #56 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623495+00:00 app[web.1]: #57 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623549+00:00 app[web.1]: #58 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623608+00:00 app[web.1]: #59 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623658+00:00 app[web.1]: #60 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623735+00:00 app[web.1]: #61 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623768+00:00 app[web.1]: #62 /app/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623769+00:00 app[web.1]: #63 {main}
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623778+00:00 app[web.1]: "} 
2024-08-06T16:47:15.623861+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.10.141 - - [06/Aug/2024:16:47:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 6609 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
2024-08-06T16:47:31.412682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/hunter/message" host=nufaro-624c6180bb35.herokuapp.com request_id=aeb0a779-410b-426f-9678-016f277c573d fwd="177.53.24.32" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=5072 protocol=https
2024-08-06T16:47:31.411993+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.28.92 - - [06/Aug/2024:16:47:31 +0000] "GET /hunter/message HTTP/1.1" 200 3968 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/127.0.0.0

[enter image description here][3]


[enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBsbw2hf.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/J9dyQM2C.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/oz7z3WA4.png
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/JpUUb92C.png


A 500 error is an exception. You’ll need to view the logs for your Heroku app to determine the issue, fix it, and re-deploy. You can view the logs from either the Heroku dashboard or Heroku CLI. Docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs

That's a Laravel 500, so also check the logs in your project's storage/logs folder

there is nothing in the log file.
attached Heroku log file.

@Thalyson Set your LOG_CHANNEL config var to stderr so that errors are piped to Heroku’s logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging#laravel

now it returned more logs, I only put half of it so it wouldn't be too big, it still reports the generic 500 error, I only pasted half of the log

@Thalyson You’ve cut off the actual useful part of the log. You’ve pasted everything from frame #47. The start would have had the actual exception message, and the file and line number it occurred.

I updated the log, can you check?

@Thalyson Yes. Have you read the error? It’s now telling you that it can’t find files that should have been built via Vite. If you add the heroku/nodejs build pack to your app, then it should install NPM dependencies and run npm run build when you deploy your app, and build those files.

heroku/nodejs is already installed, but the error persists
I used 'npm run build' but it didn't work, is there any other command?

@Thalyson If you have the heroku/nodejs build pack added to your app, then it should automatically run npm run build when deploying. Take a look at the output of your last deployment to see if the command ran. You should see output similar to this: https://imgur.com/SYsgalE

run 'npm run build', but it remains the same

command executed in the console

@Thalyson Why does the Vite error reference “/public/script.js”? You’re meant to use Vite to build files in your resources directory. You don’t need Vite to add a vanilla JavaScript file in your public directory to your web page.
